# MySQL load data infile function and format of the csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

So I need some help, I'm stuck on this for hours. So I have this array of data in PHP which I write into a CSV file using the fputcsv function. Now the data gets saved into a CSV file and it is of the following format:

```
Becoming Human, "becoming_human_uk", "2011", 
Bed of Roses, "bed_of_roses", "2008", 
Bed of Roses, "Bed_of_Roses_2008", "2008", 
Bedlam, "bedlam", "2011",
```

This goes on for ~10k more rows. Now up to this point it is all hunky dory. However now I want to import all of this data from the CSV to my database table. To do this I use the LOAD DATA INFILE mysql function of the following format:

```
$sql="LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/series.csv' INTO TABLE series FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' (title, link, year)";
```

It is now here where the problem lies. Only one row gets inserted into the database and its the first row. I suspect the problem lies in these optional parameters like TERMINATED BY or ENCLOSED BY. I put fields to *optionally enclosed by* because the first field is not enclosed in "" while the other two are. Also the fields terminate by (,) so I guess that is ok. This only leaves the *line termination* and I don't know if this is correct. There might be something else wrong with this. Or can I somehow better format the input of the data into the CSV so that all the fields are enclosed the same way. So if someone can help me spot the problem here I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: why not go from array to db directly.

Comment: The most common reason I've found for only one row being inserted is the line terminator definition not matching the actual line terminator

Comment: I can't go from array to db because i have about half a million rows and loading the data from csv to db is faster. At least that's what I'm trying to find out now.

Comment: I also think it's the line terminator but I tried almost everything and it still doesn't work.

Comment: i cant see how the creation of a file then import in to db is faster than going directly to the db.

Comment: @Emcho Can you provide CREATE TABLE for series table, so I could reproduce the error?

Comment: @Sumoanand \\r\\n is correct - it will be transfered to \r\n - i checked

Comment: You can do direct db insertion too(much faster) but not by separate insert statement for every record. You need to do combined insertion: `http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/`

Comment: @Dagon, LOAD DATA INFILE is *much* faster than inserting row by row - [up to 10-20x faster](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-speed.html).  Even after the overhead of writing the CSV file to disk, this can make enough difference that it's faster to use LOAD DATA INFILE than going direct to the db.  The more rows to insert, the greater the difference.  And of course hardware can make a difference too.

Comment: @BillKarwin, well now you tell me, guess i have been doing it wrong for the last decade!

Comment: I have a lot of data and I read about LOAD DATA INFILE and I previously tried doing a single insert statement, however it took too long for the query to finish. So I agree with Bill here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested in MySQL 5.5.31 and this worked:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'series.csv' INTO TABLE series 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
  (title, link, year);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I had to edit the csv file:

- Don't put spaces after commas.
- Don't put a comma at the end of the line.
- Don't use `\r\n` if your file contains only `\n` newlines.
- Don't put spaces at the end of the line.
- I was testing in the MySQL client, not in PHP, so I removed the double-backslashes.

Comment: Im just about the make the modifications you did. I'll post back the results.

Comment: Ok I changed the format of the CSV file and now it is like this: data1,data2,data3 - I removed the " and the spaces. I also removed the optionally closed by '\"' parameter now. So fields are terminated by (,) and lines are terminated by (\n). But now I'm not getting anything inputted into the db.

Comment: No wait it's ok just needed to remove some commas that were in the title. Works now. Thanks a lot for the help Bill.

Comment: Just an idea to keep the commas etc in the titles use something quite unlikely as delimiter as for example §§§,  fputcsv($fp, $fields, "§§§"); (I guess there is a better way though)