# MySQL load data infile function not stopping when loading from CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Ok so I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845044/mysql-load-data-infile-function-and-format-of-the-csv-file) a few minutes ago and the issue regarding that was solved. Now continuing in the direction of that question, I have another problem. The query that inputs the data from the file, inputs it (and very fast if I might add) but then does not stop. Instead it continues to add additional rows of empty data since the rows in the CSV just go on to infinite, and so it just inputs more empty rows to the db. How can I stop this? Is there an *eof* mark that I can use here or what.

Comment: there can not be an *infinite* number of rows in the csv.

Comment: Well in my populated CSV file there are currently around 9k rows, but then if you scroll down the empty rows keep on going. This is why I think the query inputs also these empty rows to the db.

Comment: Ensure that you don't have blank lines (lines with only a CR) at the end of the CSV. Open the file in a text editor (not excel) and delete all the blank lines at the end.

Comment: infinite rows is a term to describe a buffered list